# Having trouble with adding MYSQL Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I am attempting to show a MYSQL array in a HTML dropdown, but I am having issues.

For example:

[image: Click here to see website result]
It turns up like that. It gets the number of rows correct but it doesn't actually show the text. Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
                                                        //db connection
mysql_connect("localhost","censoreduser","censoredpass");
mysql_select_db("censoreddb");

//query
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `email` FROM `accounts` WHERE `type` = 'NotBanned'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['email'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
?>
```

Comment: Boss peoples are using 4G, Stop using `mysql_*` it's removed from php7

Comment: Do your users a favor and delete that old obsolete `mysql_*`.  A simple upgrade to PHP 7+ and this code is broken into pieces

Comment: So i change it to mysqli_query?

Comment: It's weird, you are using SSL but still using a backwards API

Comment: I edit your question please check it now

Comment: @Nerks no. Go and read a proper tutorial. It's bad practice that you are learning PHP by jumping in to something beyond you. You should start with the basics and PHP101 as well as best security practices

Comment: Please read it https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @rawathemant: don't edit in solutions into questions. If the solution is to add columns to the query, *use an answer*. Now the question is useless to future visitors, as you altered the code to remove the source of the error in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query with

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `type` = 'NotBanned'");
```

**You forget to select id with email**

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I'll check it out!

Comment: Doesn't work. Still get the same result ;( Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: @Nerks : which php version you are using?

Comment: PHP verson 5.6 @C2486

Comment: You have 'id' column in your table?

Comment: Yes, I do have an ID column.

Comment: Now check, You use name in drop down that you never select in query.

Comment: You have to select those column that you want to use in HTML

Comment: Thanks dude! That helped very nicely.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. can you please up vote my answer.

Comment: Yep! Done. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Your suggested edit is incorrect. Thanks tho! I'll change it. Where it says  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>'; it should be  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['email'].'</option>';

Comment: Ok. I thought you want to show name that's why i was selected name instead of email

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:-

```
<?php
    //db connection
    mysql_connect("localhost","censoreduser","censoredpass");
    mysql_select_db("censoreddb");

    //query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `type` = 'NotBanned'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) ;
?>

<select class="form-control" id="email">
    <option value="0">Choose Record</option>

<?php

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>

            <option value="<?=$row['id'];?>"><?=$row['email'];?></option>

<?php

        }

    }

?>

</select>
```

Check this , it will work .